# How to configure puppeteer to use current browser user?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, puppeteer

How to configure puppeteer to use current browser user.
Sometimes, I want to get some information through my account, and with my chrome plugin that is installed currently.
So, I try to configure the "userDataDir" fields, I don't know if I configured it incorrectly, but it never works.

```js
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome',
        headless: false,
        userDataDir: '~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default',
    })
```

Does anyone have the same problem as me?

Comment: Not sure if this solves your need, but if you remove the executablePath key (thus using the browser that already comes bundled with Puppeteer) and define a different userDataDir, you can log into your account in Puppeteer's browser and persist that account info for subsequent script runs